Probability of Safe Passage Across a Busy Street: Probability, sets, and interval
I am a high school student looking to investigate this certain problem for a research project (supposed to be beyond high school level). Here is the problem in plain words:

I am going to cross a single-lane road in the next hour. It takes $5$ second for me to cross. However, there are $50$ cars passing the road within the hour, each taking $3$ seconds to pass. Both me and the cars cross/pass at random time, regardless of if we see each other. What is the probability that I will cross the road safely?

For those who don't like reading wordy questions, here is a mathematical version rephrased by ChatGPT:

Find the probability that $[t, t+5] \cap [t_i, t_i+3]=\phi$ for $i=1,2,...,50.$, where $t$ is chosen uniformly at random from $[0, 3600]$

I am more than happy if someone could please point me the right direction for which topics to research/study to solve this question. I am also happy to take any suggestion for any topics I could do instead for my research project.

Don't use ChatGPT for math, it's a waste of time.  In this case:  it's irrelevant when you start.  Say you start right now.  What is the probability that a car passes in the next $5$ seconds?

Don't overthink. Consider the 5 seconds that you use to pass the road. What is the probability that a car passes the road during that time.
